# How to change main app language on a Cordova project before exporting to Xcode project?

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode, cordova, localization

I'm creating a Cordova Project on Eclipse Luna, using the THYM (The Hybrid Mobile) Eclipse plugin, version 0.3. Using Cordova 3.7.2(Android) and Cordova 3.8(iOS).

Every time i have a release, i export the cordova project to a native project format (in my case, Xcode format and Android Studio format). But the main language on the native project formats is English, and i need to define another language (Portuguese) for it.

I know that i can do this(manually) on the MyApp-Info.plist on Xcode after the export, but that's not what i want, since this makes me manually repeat the modification every time i create a new release on Eclipse.

Some configuration on the config.xml, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the config.xml, under the `<platform name="ios">` tag

```
 <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion">
            <string>Spanish</string>
 </edit-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
<config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion" overwrite="true">
<string>Portuguese</string>
</config-file>
```

Comment: Try to explain why this is the solution. Don't post just a code snippet please

Comment: I believe this code snipped goes inside the config.xml used in Cordova. Then, by the time the project for Xcode is generated by the Cordova CLI tools, this configuration sets the language in the info.plist inside Xcode.